# @SessionScoped does not work when adding @Named

Tags: java, jsf-2, glassfish-3

Consider the following backing bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Counter {

    int counter;

    public Counter() {
        this.counter = 0;
    }

    public void Increment() {
        this.counter++;
    }

    public void Decrement() {
        this.counter--;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return this.counter;
    }

}
```

I have created a JSF-page that displays the value of the counter and has two buttons to increment and decrement it. It works as expected. However, when I add the annotation `javax.inject.Named` to the bean, it does not seem to have session scope anymore. The buttons still work (the click is handled on the server-side), but the value of the counter always remains zero. I am using the annotation because in my real application I need to inject other beans into this one, and this annotation seems to be required (please correct me if I am wrong). What is the reason for this behavior? What can I do to work around it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot mix JSF with CDI annotations. Use the one or the other. In this case, you need to import [`javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) instead of `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`.

Comment: This works, but requires the bean to be serializable (which is no problem, I just added the comment for completeness).

Comment: It's by the way also recommended to let JSF `@SessionScoped` and `@ViewScoped` beans implement `Serializable`. JSF only doesn't emit errors, but just warnings.